# How to set OpenGL version in either EGL or GLSurfaceView?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, egl

For the OpenGL Android project I am working on, I need ES 2.0, but I need the control of rendering buffers/surfaces I am accustomed to achieving by using EGL. For I cannot figure out any way to render to an offscreen buffer using GLSurfaceView, and then never displaying the buffer. Even if I use GLSurfaceView.EGLContextFactory, I cannot think of any way to accomplish this without EGL 1.2 functions/constants not included in Android's EGL package (e.g. EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION).

So the first obvious question is: is there a way to either 1) use EGL with ES 2.0 despite the omission of EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION and of eglBindAPI()? 2) is there some new API for setting the rendering context used before GLSurfaceView's callback surfaceCreated(EGLConfig) is called?

Answer (score 12):

If you can live with the default EGLContextFactory and EGLConfigChooser, you can use the [setEGLContextClientVersion()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setEGLContextClientVersion%28int%29) method of the GLSurfaceView.

Otherwise, if you're writing your own [EGLContextFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.EGLContextFactory.html) and [EGLConfigChooser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.EGLConfigChooser.html), just define the constants yourself. In the config chooser, define

```
private static final int EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT = 4;
```

then pass this as the value for EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE to eglChooseConfig, together with other attributes you desire:

```
int attribs[] = {
    EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE,   mRedSize,
    EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, mGreenSize,
    EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE,  mBlueSize,
    EGL10.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, mAlphaSize,
    EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, mDepthSize,
    EGL10.EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, mSampleBuffers,
    EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
    EGL10.EGL_NONE
};
```

For the context factory, define

```
private static final int EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION = 0x3098;
```

and use this when creating a context:

```
public EGLContext createContext(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display, EGLConfig eglConfig) 
{
  int[] attrib_list = {
    EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2,
    EGL10.EGL_NONE 
  };

  EGLContext context = egl.eglCreateContext(display, eglConfig, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, attrib_list);

  return context;
}
```

When you've written those, pass them to [setEGLContextFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setEGLContextFactory%28android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.EGLContextFactory%29) and [setEGLConfigChooser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setEGLConfigChooser%28android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.EGLConfigChooser%29), respectively.